# Wicket AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, wicket

I have a problem with the component `AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior`.
When I add this component to the main page, springs security enables authorization, as a protected page. When I remove this component from the page, everything gets good.

> My UNSECURED_RESOURCE_LIST "/resources/**", "/assets/**", "/css/**",
>   "/fonts/**", "/webjars/**", "/img/**", "/js/**".

Here is my wicket page, as you can see when I add AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior component, spring security enables authorization.

```
public class FrontPage extends WebPage {
    private List<Language> languages = Arrays.asList(Language.RUSSIAN, 
    Language.ENGLISH);
    private Language language = Language.RUSSIAN;
    private DropDownChoice languagesDD;

public FrontPage() {
    languagesDD = new DropDownChoice<String>("languages", new 
    PropertyModel(FrontPage.this, "language"), new 
    PropertyModel(FrontPage.this, "languages"), new ChoiceRenderer() {
        @Override
        public Object getDisplayValue(Object object) {
            Language language = (Language) object;
            if (Language.RUSSIAN.equals(language)) {
                return getString("Language.RUSSIAN");
            } else if (Language.ENGLISH.equals(language)) {
                return getString("Language.ENGLISH");
            }
            return super.getDisplayValue(object);
        }
    });
    add(languagesDD);
    languagesDD.add(new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("change") {
        @Override
        protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            //iWebSession().setLocaleString(language.getCode());
            //setResponsePage(FrontPage.class);
        }
    });
}
```

}

[image]

Comment: Can you more specific ?share the code also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found a solution.
Just add "/wicket/**" to your unsecured resource list.

Answer (score 0):

When i comment this component. Everything become OK.
I guess that maybe the AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior component is trying to use the resources that are in the protected area.
I added the resources to the non-security list.
So I cannot understand why spring enables authorization when I add AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior component.

```
public class FrontPage extends WebPage {
    private List<Language> languages = Arrays.asList(Language.RUSSIAN, 
    Language.ENGLISH);
    private Language language = Language.RUSSIAN;
    private DropDownChoice languagesDD;

public FrontPage() {
    languagesDD = new DropDownChoice<String>("languages", new PropertyModel(FrontPage.this, "language"), new PropertyModel(FrontPage.this, "languages"), new ChoiceRenderer() {
        @Override
        public Object getDisplayValue(Object object) {
            Language language = (Language) object;
            if (Language.RUSSIAN.equals(language)) {
                return getString("Language.RUSSIAN");
            } else if (Language.ENGLISH.equals(language)) {
                return getString("Language.ENGLISH");
            }
            return super.getDisplayValue(object);
        }
    });
    add(languagesDD);
//        languagesDD.add(new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("change") {
//            @Override
//            protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
//                //iWebSession().setLocaleString(language.getCode());
//                //setResponsePage(FrontPage.class);
//            }
//        });
    }
}
```

[image]